# Nginx source installation refuses to recognise headers-more-nginx-module config file exists (installing on Ubuntu)

Tags: nginx, module, installation, ubuntu-14.04, configure

I have an nginx installation I need to configure from source on an Ubuntu machine. The source files and the module have been provided on my local drive and I have been given the following instructions:

```
cd ~/Platform
tar xzf nginx-1.6.*
cd ~/Platform/nginx-1.6.*
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --add-module=/home/user/Platform/header-more-nginx-module/
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /var/log/nginx
```

Running `./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --add-module=/home/user/Platform/header-more-nginx-module/` results in this error:

```
adding module ~/Platform/headers-more-nginx-module/
./configure: error: no ~/Platform//config was found
```

Ok, fine, I thought, so I removed the final forward slash, and changed the `/home/user` out for a tilde for good measure, and now I'm getting this error:

```
./configure: error: no ~/Platform/headers-more-nginx-module/config was found
```

Running `vi ~/Platform/headers-more-nginx-module/config` shows the config file contents so I know it's there and in the right location.

Can anyone tell me why the `./configure` command might not be finding this file despite it being present in the correct directory, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This appears to have been a relative file paths issue. Running the command from our administrative user referencing the development users seems to have worked. Perhaps an issue with alternative interpretations of the tilde when referenced with vi vs when referenced by the ./configure command.

Comment: Hi there, I'm having the same issue when running the command on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk EC2 Linux 2 instance